# Getting Value from Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am a beginner at Javascript and am running into a little problem. It is a homework problem, but it is graded based on completion only, so I am only trying to figure out the right answer for myself.

I am supposed to define a function, repeatUntil, that takes in two other functions, say f(returns a number) and g (returns a boolean value). The functionality of repeatUntil is to repeat function f at least once until g returns true.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function repeatUntil(f, cond) {
   var f1;

   do{
     f1 = f;
     return f1;
   }
   while(cond(f1()));
}
```

And here is the tester/how we call it:

```
var print = console.log;
var r = repeatUntil(function(x) { return x + x }, function(x) { return x >= 20 })
print(r(2))
print("Expected: 32")
```

The function runs, but my problem right now is storing the updated value of x from the repeatUntil function. Right now the function only runs once, and the condition is not updated because I cannot pass in the updated value of x into the function g. I tried putting the result of f() into a variable, but it will only return a function and not a number.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: the do loop will run exactly once because you `return` in the body of the loop - that's just the most obvious error in your code, there's other issues once you fix that one

Comment: Since you need to call r(), your function needs to return another function

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried putting return after it exits the loop, but since the condition is not updated it's giving me an infinite loop right now.

Comment: You don't need a return, just a condition to break out of the loop, that condition is the result of your cond() call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the existing comments into an answer.

- Since you need to call `r()`, your function needs to return another function.
- The do loop will run exactly once because you return in the body of the loop

**Code**

```
function repeatUntil(f, cond) {
   return function() {
       while(cond(f()));
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Juan Mendes ! What was missing from the returned function turns out to be a param that handles the number used by f upon each computation (the x that continues to change every time f is evaluated).